# Allow user to reorder table's rows and save changes to database (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a list of photos with a property named "Order", the customer wants to be able to reorder the elements, and save changes back to the server.

Does anyone know how I can do that? On the client side (with JQuery or JavaScript) and how to send the indexes of the rows to controller ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI sortable - sorting images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511239/jquery-ui-sortable-sorting-images)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an exact duplicate (different stack for example), but that is a very good resource for this question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had to do similar, and basically you've got to manage it yourself.

A plugin like https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ will help with physically sorting items on the page, but when persisting it to DB, you'll have to manage this yourself.

From a UI perspective, you've got 2 options@

1. Make it part of the main UI flow or
2. Make it a separate "screen" / option

The first is more integrated, but works best for "coherant" page items. Tiles / images etc. The second is better for complex elements (like table rows with controls and the like).

In either case, the logic is similar:

1. Handle an event when the ordering is changed (see your plugin or choise)
2. Inspect the new ordering (you may be given just the elements changed, or you may need to look at the entire set)
3. Use meta-data (that perhaps you write in as `data-` attributes on page creation) to map each element on the page to one of your data objects. You may be using knockout etc. which would make this simpler...
4. Persist the change to the database (on user save / always).

For step 4, you've just got to implement a new controller action which accepts the ordered data set you have (list of id's, etc. etc.). It then talks to the DB to update this ordering / set ordinal column.

If you already have an "edit" style page, where you are posting back to the controller with an existing, composite model (`List<MyThingEditVM> model`), then add a hidden form field to each element containing the `Order` value, edit this client side when re-ordering and then it'll get sent through with the rest of the form data on post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked @ DataTables - http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/

Have used them in the past and were very useful - lots of good documentation on their site as well